# I cannot add new namespace " because the name is already in use!"

Tags: symfony, namespaces, composer-php

I have a problem with adding new namespace to my project. I wanted to add "App\Builder\QueryBuilder" to my classes but I cannot "because the name is already in use". So I tried add new namespace in my composer.json

```
 "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/",
            "CustomApp\\": "src/"
        }
```

but still I have the same problem.

Comment: Clear your cache by deleting var/cache, verify your don't have QueryBuilder accidentally defined somewhere else (typically a copy/paste error) and then try again.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't add here 2 namespaces for same directory because then how composer will now, which namespace should be used for files in this directory?

Second thing, verify whether you already don't have QueryBuilder defined somewhere or include more code than this.

Comment: I though that composer verify which namespace should be used by using 'namespace' like 'namespace CustomApp\...'